# Jetty mac encoding to UTF-8

Tags: macos, encoding, utf-8, jetty

I'm running Jetty on OSX on my dev environment. Currently character encoding seems to be faulti (probably mac-roman), overriding Jetty default. How can I force the encoding to be UTF-8? This problem seems to appear only on OSX, linux/windows works fine.

I'm running Jetty from terminal so eclipse-specific solutions aren't of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem here however we start Jetty from the javaWrapper (and which should not make a difference).

The only parameter I can see making an impact is setting the file.encoding System Property e.g. `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

EDIT
( our macs locale are set to utf-8 )

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as it's the same parameter that ended up solving the problem. The mistake of thinking it should be a Jetty-parameter was mine...

Answer (score 5):

Apparently I was wrong in blaming Jetty for this problem. The reason was maven and how maven brings in the default encoding java-settings.

Setting this env-variable seemed to solve the problem:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

[Answer found from here](http://blog.lidalia.org.uk/2011/04/setting-default-java-file-encoding-to.html).

Comment: This fixed my encoding issues running a mvn jetty on windows through cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

To set the default character encoding for jetty you can set the system property 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoding.charset' to whatever you like.  This will affect the encoding and decoding for either the query string of a URL or the content of a POST HTTP request.

Also, for a long time (maybe early 6.1.x timeframe) now this has been utf-8 by default so I am not certain this is the issue your are seeing.

So it is clear, jetty has been an eclipse project for a number of years now so that above system settings isn't an eclipse specific setting, it is just an artifact of our being at eclipse naming wise. :)

cheers

Comment: upvote for the information value on parameters starting with "eclipse"

Comment: I think the URL encoding is a different issue than the poster mentioned (The default file encoding).  (s)he is asking about a JVM setting, not an HTTP specific setting.